# Getting Server Error 500 while inserting large amount of data in mysql database through php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Getting *Server Error 500* while inserting large amount of data in **mysql** database through **php**.

Actually I'm developing a scratch coupon scheme. And for that I've to create about a lac coupons at a time. But after about 14-16minutes it gives *Server Error-500 which stops my execution* and creates only about 16k-17k coupons.

I'm already increase the execution time, but it doesn't work-

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
set_time_limit(0);
```

And used mysql insert batch query (creates block of 1000queries then run, and so on..)
Something Like-

```
INSERT INTO scratch_coupon(coupon_id, coupon_code, gift_id) 
VALUES 
(NULL, '123456789', 5),
(NULL, '123456789', 5),
(NULL, '123456789', 5),
....and so on till 1000queries
```

Why is this is happening & what will be the solution ?
Kindly assist.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Server error 500` errors relate to an Apache crash, so its not your PHP script being timed out. I would be tempted to run that kind of process from the command line anyway as it will obviously take more than a few second to run. This would also take Apache out of the equation, and if it is your script causing the problem then it will still crash, and prove its your script causing the issue, or prove your script is not the problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use loop, it's more stable and reliable than sending single massive query.

Also, you can set your script to add let's say 5,000 rows, and you can set cron jobs to launch script every 5 minutes for 10 times. That will give you 50,000 rows in 50 minutes, but browser won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

this is a one-time process to fill the database, right? 
Then why not write the queries to a textfile first (name it for example createoupons.sql), and run the query using the commandline:

`mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < createcoupons.sql`

this is the safest way to import large amounts of data.